# Multiple server petitions in angular

Tags: node.js, angularjs, server

My app's frontend, built in angular v1.4.5, is sending multiple petitions to the server, built in node v 8.0.0, when these take a little more time to manage.

For example

```
$http.post("http://192.168.2.1:8080/times/all_hourly_with_matter_and_client_by_Status",{"Status":'not-billed'})
  .success(function (data) 
  {
           console.log(data);
  })
   .error(function (err) 
  {
      console.log(err);
  });
```

When the frontend detects no response from the server after some time (I don't know exactly how much) it sends again the petition by itself (sometinmes more than once).
These petitions get to the server, which executes every single one of them:
[image]

I don't really understand what is happening, because angular only executes once the .success and it never gets into the .error

Anyone knows how to fix this, avoiding changing the general setting of the server's response time limit? (We do sometimes need the server to wait, if the petiton is big).

In this example I'm showing you, the petition is for an object list and it doesn't cause any more harm than a little delay, but when I ask for the creation of an object, this object sometimes is created twice.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I suppose your http client is configured to do this somewhere. You could change this config.
To be honest - such long running requests are far from optimal, you could think about a queuing system for this case? (Generate/Map the data with one request and then get the data later with a second request)

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is not what you want to hear, but I think that for such slow responses, you need to change your pattern a little bit.

What I would do is:

- return 200 as the server has received the data;
- create another endpoint to check if the submit is ok;
- on the client-side, make a GET request every 5 seconds or so, with a setInterval, the check endpoint

The behaviour of the browser or the library is very strange, though. 
I have not found anything helpful googling around.